# How to create Mobilefirst a new Splash screen

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How to create Mobilefirst a new Splash screen. If I create a project default IBM logo is appearing I have to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You start by googling. This in turn will bring you to the IBM MobileFirst Platform Developer Center / Knowledge Center. There you search for it...

- [Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_application_resources.html): search for "splash image"

The splash screen is an image.
You simply need to replace the image with your own.

You did not mention what is the intended environment... iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone, so you'll need to check that on your own.

The Knowledge Center topic details the names and locations of the image file(s).